# Правильное использование запросов в приложении

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, рефакторинг

Здравствуйте, тут недавно возник у меня такой вопрос... Пишу приложение, которое обширно работает с БД и задумался над тем как более эстетичнее хранить запросы в коде, потому что некоторые запросы очень большими получаются и режут глаз. К примеру:

```
SELECT t.name, t.number, t.address, t.personal_data, t.date_birth, p.name, pr.name 
FROM teachers t 
   LEFT JOIN predmets p ON t.id_predmet = p.id 
   LEFT JOIN professions pr ON t.id_profession = pr.id
WHERE pr.name = '...'
ORDER BY t.name
```

И вот такой вопрос приходится писать в ф-ии и после этого его выполнять... Может как-то хранят запросы в XML и потом их достают, может есть другие способы? Или не стоит париться на счет этого? Знаю про views, но насколько я знаю они замедляют выполнение запроса, когда разрастется БД, думаю что это будет ощутимо...

Comment: А еще есть хранимые процедуры, свет клином на view не сошелся...

Comment: И мне кажется это дело вкуса, меня запросы прямо в коде устраивают. И у вас запрос очень маленький, у меня экрана по 3 бывают и то ничего.

Comment: Знаю про хранимые процедуры, но не под каждый же их запрос писать

Comment: у нас есть отчетная легаси БД(более 20 лет) + 3 клиента для нее. Есть самый базовый набор запросов который зашит в код, остальные запросы хранятся в самой БД и оттуда берутся по необходимости. Это позволяет более менее универсально использовать одинаковые запросы для всех 3 приложений. Возможно вам подойдет что-то подобное

Comment: Ещё бывают всякие ORM, можно их попробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VIEW не замедляют скорость работы, если колличество данных в таблице не превышает 30-35 млн

Можете использовать packages, создав в них процедуру (procedure) и функцию (function) и обращаться уже непосредственно к ней. Например

```
create or replace package CC_EMPLOYEE as

type trec_teachers is record( 
  name varchar(255 char) -- указываем возвращаемое значение и кодировку
, number (number)
, address varchar(500 char)
, personal_data date
, date_birth date
);

type tt_teacher_table is table of trec_teachers;
```

Тело пакета

```
create or replace package_body CC_EMPLOYEE as -- создаем тело - место хранения функций
function get_teachers_table() -- создаем саму функцию
return tt_teacher_table pipelined is -- возвращаем данные на временную таблицу

/* вставить ваш код*/

end get_teachers_table; -- завершаем функцию

end CC_EMPLOYEE; -- завершаем тело
```

Обращаться с указанием пакета и функции. т.е.
select * from cc_employee.get_teachers_table

В скорости не страдает особо, если объем данных не большой и выглядит элегантнее, чем десять тысяч вьюх

---

UPD использую Oracle 11g в качестве бд, субд pl/sql 8.0.0.1480

В силу невозможности писать комментарии поясню про view

view - сильная сторона, которая уменьшает колличество строк в коде до минимума, но существуют такие ситуации, когда необходим входной параметр. В view кроме как глобального параметра невозможно ничего применять, в pkg же можно задать выходной параметр в самой функции

Объявление глобального параметра для передачи во view

```
create or replace package SHC_FLT_PKG as
PROCEDURE SET_TEACHER_NAME ( p_TEACHER_NAME IN VARCHAR);
FUNCTION GET_TEACHER_NAME RETURN VARCHAR;
end SHC_FLT_PKG

create or replace package_body SHC_FLT_PKG as 
a_TEACHER_NAME VARCHAR;

 PROCEDURE SET_TEACHER_NAME( p_TEACHER_NAME IN VARCHAR)
  IS
  BEGIN
    a_TEACHER_NAME := p_TEACHER_NAME;
  END SET_TEACHER_NAME;

  FUNCTION GET_TEACHER_NAME RETURN VARCHAR
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN a_TEACHER_NAME;
  END GET_TEACHER_NAME;

END SHC_FLT_PKG;
```

Но глобальные переменный ведут в ад.

Поэтому в пакете CC_EMPLOYEE достаточно добавить в функцию

```
function get_teachers_table(
teachers_name varchar
)
return tt_teacher_table pipelined is
```

И при передаче уже обзывать в используемом вам языке (java, php) этот входной параметр (:teachers_name)

Comment: *VIEW не замедляют скорость работы, если колличество данных в таблице не превышает 30-35 млн* Зависит от СУБД, и легко может стать неверным. Самое страшное при использовании view - потеря статистики таблиц и отрыв от подходящих индексов. Бывали даже случаи, когда "оптимизация" с выносом подзапроса (обычного, некоррелированного) в представление укладывала сервер...

Comment: Интересно, а зачем вы пишите примеры с packages, вам как то удалось узнать, что у спрашивающего именно Oracle ? Ответ не применим для других СУБД чуть менее, чем полностью. И да, view и производительность в очень многих случаях вещи несовместимые.

Comment: Не знаю, смогу ли комментировать, но напишу. Он не указал бд, я написал то, чем сам пользуюсь. Не поможет ему - поможет кому-нибудь другому.